# How do you solve this loop so that the button 'read more' only collapses in each card?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

This code creates a card component but the **read more button** collapses **all the cards** but I only want to **collapse individually** in each card when I click the button.

```
{% for job in jobs%}
  <div class="card w-100 mb-2">
    <div class="jobs card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Position: {{ job.title }}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-title font-weight-normal">Location: {{ job.location }}</h6>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Read More</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</a>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <hr>
        <h6 class="">Requirements</h6>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple elements with the same ID (demo). You need to differentiate those elements somehow. I would use [loop.index](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)

```
{% for job in jobs%}
  <div class="card w-100 mb-2">
    <div class="jobs card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Position: {{ job.title }}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-title font-weight-normal">Location: {{ job.location }}</h6>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo-{{loop.index}}">Read More</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</a>
      <div id="demo-{{loop.index}}" class="collapse">
        <hr>
        <h6 class="">Requirements</h6>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it has to do with everything being labeled demo.

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" **data-target="#demo"**>Read More</button>

<div **id="demo"** class="collapse">

I'm not experienced with jinja
Maybe you can add something like

`data-target="#content{{job.id}}"`

`<div id="content{{job.id}}"`